# how to change http://localhost:8080 into home in breadcrumb?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, breadcrumbs

i am using this for breadcrumb in jsp

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
       <c:url var="home"   value="http://localhost:8080/" />
        <c:forEach var="bc" items="${breadcrumb.tree}" varStatus="status">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${status.index==0}">
                    <a href="/">${home}</a>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${status.index == fn:length(breadcrumb.tree)-1 && status.index!=0}">
                    »${bc.name}
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <a href="${bc.value}">»${bc.name}</a>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
</div>
```

i am getting this--`http://localhost:8080/ »products`

but i want home»products

can anyone tell me how it will be.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the value of:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

Into the variable home, which you are then outputting within the anchor tag.

Store:

```
<c:url var="home"   value="http://localhost:8080/" />
```

Output:

```
<a href="/">${home}</a>
```

Either define home within a messages file, or ignore assigning it.